# Loading swf in flash

Tags: flash

I get more information around in internet about how it do, but I have problem how right including in my "flash load external swf" the "as3 xml full stream gallery" . And how to focus gallery in centre.

Comment: Have you even tried google? 0.0001 seconds brought up about 50,000 links on how to include one .swf in another.

Answer (score 1):

Loading is easy enough:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("myFlashThing.swf"));
addChild(loader);
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "how focus gallery in center" but if you want to center it:

```
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaded);
function onLoad(evt:Event):void{
  loader.x = stage.stageWidth / 2 - loader.content.width / 2;
  loader.y = stage.stageHeight / 2 - loader.content.height / 2;
}
```

(untested, but its something along those lines)